# How to use mapped field in hibernate query?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have implemented one-to-many relationships for entity. So those are mapped with another entity to pass the value.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="part_id")
    public Part getPart() {
        return part;
```

`part_id doesn't create getters and setters with @column`.Its only setting up with relationship.

But in other scenarios i have check these fields in query.I'm trying to use Criteria to find the values

Its giving me exception `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: part_id`
because didn't generate getter with @Column property.Could you please advise how to use these fields in query ?

if add getters and setters, its giving `org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:`.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you add the PartVesion Pojo

Comment: @suresh if add pojo , its getting error "org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: ".

Comment: No i am asking to post the PartVesion POJO Class.

Comment: @suresh added pojo class, please advise..

Comment: your mapping is wrong. Check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bi-Direction Association([link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#collections-bidirectional)) should be as below.

```
@Entity
public class Troop {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="troop")
    public Set<Soldier> getSoldiers() {
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Soldier {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="troop_fk")
    public Troop getTroop() {
    ...
}
```

Kindly check the configuration. If possible use hibernate tools to generate the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using names of database columns, names of persistent properties should be used. In this case name of the persistent property is part. If goal is to fetch all such entities that are related to part with given id, then following is way to go (name of the `id` property in `Part` is assumed to be `id`):

```
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("part.id", partId));
```